# Connection refused error in outbound request in k8s app container. Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-pod

Updated

I have some script that initializes our service.
The script fails when it runs in the container because of ***connection refused*** error in the first outbound request (to external service) in the script.
We tried to add a loop that makes curl and if it fails, re-try, if not - continuous the script.
Sometimes it succeeds for the first time, sometimes it fails 10-15 times in a row.
We recently started using istio
What may be a reason??

Comment: `Connection refused` usually indicates that there is no service(program) listening for connections. Are you sure that application you are trying to connect to is listening and the port you are connecting to is correct? @Tantre

Comment: @HelloWorld I mentioned that exactly the same script runs in init-container just a moment before app-container starts to run the script. So yes, external service is listening and accessible

Comment: Can you exec to app-container and curl or netcat the external service? Just to see if the connection is being established?

Comment: I added loop with curl that continues if the response is 000 (connection refused) and breaks if any other response. Sometimes it works from the first try, sometimes doesn't work after 10 re-tries. I don't understand what is the issue...

Comment: Is this external service inside of your cluster? Are you using k8s service endpoint to connect to it? If so, check the selector. maybe this service selector is shareing labels with other pods and thus trafic gets randomly routed to some pods. Run `kubectl get endpoints <servicenaem>` and check ENDPOINTS column whether it contains some unexpected ips.

Answer (score 1):

With istio 1.7 comes a new feature that configures the pod to start the sidecar first and hold every other container untill the sidecar is started.

Just set `values.proxy.holdApplicationUntilProxyStarts` to true.

Please note that the feature is still experimental.

Comment: we tried to wait for the localhost:15000 (IstioProxy) port to return 200OK before making an external network connection: it didn't help. still got connection refused. is there any other way to ensure the proxy can now process external hostname requests ?

Comment: Istio proxy ```info Envoy proxy is ready``` came up in 3 seconds

Comment: Do you have mtls enabled? There seams to be a bug if a sidecar with mtls tries to connect to a service that doesn't have a sidecar. And are there any errors in the envoy logs when logging is set to trace?

Answer (score 1):

It is a famous istio bug https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/11130 ( App container unable to connect to network before Istio's sidecar is fully running) it seems the Istio proxy will not start in parallel , it is waiting for the app container to be ready. a sequential startup sequence as one blogger mentioned (https://medium.com/@marko.luksa/delaying-application-start-until-sidecar-is-ready-2ec2d21a7b74) quote: `most Kubernetes users assume that after a pod’s init containers have finished, the pod’s regular containers are started in parallel. It turns out that’s not the case.`

containers will start in order defined by the Deployment spec YAML.
so the biggest question is will the Istio proxy envoy will start while the first container is stuck in a curl-loop . (egg and chicken problem) .
App container script performs:

```
until curl --head localhost:15000 ; do echo "Waiting for Istio Proxy to start" ; sleep 3 ; done
```

as far as I saw: that script doesn't help a bit. proxy is up but connection to external hostname return "connection refused"